# Unit tests - How to refactor a call to a static class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, static

I'm attempting to add unit tests to an existing code base and am pretty much falling at the first hurdle due to how the site is constructed.

To give you some detail, every controller in this site inherits from a base controller called SiteController and that controller's constructor populates some data using a static helper class.

For example

```
 public class HomeController : SiteController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
          //Do stuff here
        }    
    }
```

And here's the base controller

```
public class SiteController
{
    public SiteController()
    {
        viewModel = CategoryHelper.GetAllCategories();
    }
}
```

And the static GetAllCategories helper method

```
 public static class CategoryHelper
    {
       public static IList<string> GetAllCategories()
        {
          //Go off and get the categories from the WCF layer
          return _categories;
        }
    }
```

I can't mock a static class but how can I refactor this code so that I can work with it using unit tests. We already use DI throughout the site and I know the theory here - that I should wrap this static class in a layer of abstraction which is better for the code in general anyway. But the practicalities of this I'm less sure about.

It's probably obvious but my aim here is to keep the site working (obviously) but also to rewrite that static class or the call to it in such a way that I can unit test against it. I'm new to writing unit tests so am just running into these issues before getting the satisfaction of seeing even one green tick for a tests passed! It's frustrating, and doubly so when I know the theoretical solution but don't know what to actually do to the class in question to get it to work.

Comment: Are you able to be a bit more specific about which bit you're unsure of? You pretty much described exactly what you need to do, so it's not very clear to me what's tripping you up.

Comment: Or instead of using a wrapper just *stop using static classes*

Comment: What's the actual problem?  "How can I use this with unit tests" is a non-starter.  You use it by, well, using it.  While `static` should ideally be avoided in many cases and is often over-used or mis-used, it's not inherently incorrect.  What's the *actual problem* that you're facing?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I think that kind of thing is better as a next step when you already have some unit tests to catch potential regressions. The OP's approach of doing the minimum possible to get things testable is probably sensible.

Comment: Should have clarified - The actual problem in this case is that I don't know the *how* of wrapping this class in an abstraction. The static class is legacy code which I'm hoping that by forcing it into unit-test compliance will be rewritten or refactored into a nicer version.

Comment: Starts by removing the `static` keywords from the class and method so that you're forced to use instance methods. Then inject an instance of the class into your controller via constructor injection. You know how to do that part?

Comment: There are many DI frameworks that have built in tooling for asp.net MVC. What you need to do is figure out which one you want to use (*I prefer AutoFac*), and configure injection. Then start by creating a service registered as a singleton (*which mimics a static class, if there is no good reason it is static then register it as instance per request or owned instead*) and have that instance injected into your constructors and pass that reference on to the base class. Then you can fake that new dependency in your unit tests. You should also use interfaces as dependencies in your registrations.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class HomeController : SiteController
{
    public HomeController(ICategoryHelper categoryHelper) : base(categoryHelper)
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Do stuff here
    }    
}

public class SiteController
{
    public SiteController(ICategoryHelper categoryHelper)
    {
        viewModel = categoryHelper.GetAllCategories();
    }
}

public class CategoryHelper : ICategoryHelper
{
    public IList<string> GetAllCategories()
    {
        //Go off and get the categories from the WCF layer
        return _categories;
    }
}

public interface ICategoryHelper
{
    IList<string> GetAllCategories();
}
```

The most important thing is to code against an abstraction, not a concrete class. CategoryHelper is a concrete class, you want your controllers to utilize something that performs the work without caring how it's done. So your controllers should accept an interface in their constructor (and can pass it to the base controller if necessary).

Likewise, CategoryHelper should implement an interface, this is basically a contract saying "I can perform the work of an ICategoryHelper".

Then, you wire up CategoryHelper to satisfy the ICategoryHelper dependency with your dependency injector. How you do that depends on the specific tool you use ([AutoFac](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html), Ninject, SimpleInjector etc).

Note: a caching pattern may be better here if the categories don't change often.